# Use web.sitemap to control page access

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, web-config, web.sitemap

I was setting up permissions for pages in a ASP.NET website with `<location>` tags in web.config, something similar to this:

```
<location path="Users.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

However, I also have a web.sitemap which basically contains the same information, i.e. which user roles can see/access which pages. A snippet from my web.sitemap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="Home">
    ... lots of nodes here ...
    <siteMapNode url="users.aspx" roles="Administrator" title="users" description="Edit users" />
    ...
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Is there some kind of nifty way of using web.sitemap *only* to configure access? The `<location>` tags are quite verbose, and I don't like having to duplicate this information.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for [SecurityTrimmingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.securitytrimmingenabled.aspx). See this [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/p/714465/714465.aspx) and [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/dannychen/archive/2006/03/16/553005.aspx) for more details.

So `Web.config` restricts access from direct URL typing and `Web.sitemap` - from URLs being displayed

Comment: Yes, that's. And I'd like Web.sitemap to take of both restricting access and displaying it.  I tried adding the XmlSiteMapProvider specifically as suggested in the article, but it doesn't do what I'm looking for AND it makes my code blow up in other places. :/

Comment: @Jakob Gade: I got no success in my own project to implement you described using ASP.NET built-in providers so I did next: a number of sitemap nodes just for menu displaying. And separated XML security roles matrix used by my own class being invoked on Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can define a SiteMapProvider in your web.config, and use the CurrentNode property to get the SiteMapNode related to the requested page.

First declare your siteMap provider (web.config) :

```
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultXmlSiteMapProvider">
  <providers>
    <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="DefaultXmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Sample code for page access control with CurrentNode (you can do it better ;)) :

```
bool hasAccess = false;

if (SiteMap.CurrentNode == null)
    throw new ApplicationException("Page not present in SiteMap : " + this.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

if (SiteMap.CurrentNode.Roles.Count > 0)
{
    // All roles or no roles
    if (SiteMap.CurrentNode.Roles.Contains("*") == true)
    {
        hasAccess = true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < SiteMap.CurrentNode.Roles.Count; index++)
        { 
            string role = SiteMap.CurrentNode.Roles[index].ToString();
            hasAccess = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(role);
            if (hasAccess == true)
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note I added the everyone role (*), very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of my own `SiteMapProvider` which throws an exception where user being requested a page (node) has no right to do that (his role isn't in the list of node's roles)

```
public class XmlSiteMapProvider : System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider
{
    public override bool IsAccessibleToUser(HttpContext context, SiteMapNode node)
    {
        var roles = node.Roles.OfType<string>();
        if (roles.Contains("*") || (roles.Count(r => context.User.IsInRole(r)) > 0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InsufficientRightsException();
        }
    }
}
```

To implement my own roles logic I also made my own `RoleProvider`.